# Attaching ceiling ground wire when fixture socket does not have the green screw for attaching grnd wire

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

Ceiling ground wire is available, but fixture socket does not have the ground wire screw for attaching same.  Is there a way to "fake" it?

Comment: Added a general answer. If you can identify the model of light fixture or post a photo it will be easier to provide more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

Is the fixture made of metal? If it does not have external metal components (such as a case or cage) then it would have no use for a safety ground. The safety ground is connected to conductive surfaces that shouldn't normally carry power, but if you don't have conductive surfaces then it is not applicable.

However, if the fixture *does* have external metal components but simply lacks a screw, you can ground it by creating a conductive path between those metal components and your ground wire. If your electrical box is metal, you can do this easily by ensuring the box is grounded, and then using metal screws to attach the fixture. Otherwise, you need to bond a ground wire to the fixture. This might be doable using one of the existing screws/attachment points. Otherwise, you may need to drill a hole in the fixture, tap it, and install a ground screw and pigtail.

Comment: Not solder -- solder alone isn't a legal way to connect -- you'd need to drill a hole and put in a ground screw.

Comment: I agree with no solder on the ground, my large 3 phase cords have solder for the 3 legs but the ground lug is compression and it cannot be soldered per the listing instructions.

Comment: I believe for household-type electrical soldering is never a proper method of connection.